# How to put jssor slider count in caption

Tags: php, jssor

I have a jssor slider working, including displaying captions.  Each caption shows a title in the first line and a description in the lines below the title.  I'm looking to add the slider count to the caption, so to the right of the title I would show, for example, "2 of 47".
Based on another post I found, I added the below code to the js:

```
function DisplayIndex() {
$("#displayIndex").text(jssor_slider2.$CurrentIndex() + 1 + " of " + jssor_slider2.$SlidesCount());
}

DisplayIndex();
jssor_slider2.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, DisplayIndex);
```

I also added the `"<div id='displayIndex'"` line to the php code, subordinate to caption div, as below:

```
echo "<div class='caption2_text'>";
echo "<h1>$title</h1>";
echo "<p>$desc</p>";
echo "<div id='displayIndex' u='any' style='position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 790px; width: 100px; height: 26px;'></div>";
echo "</div>";
```

The count appears, but is in the inner container rather than in the caption, so any full width picture overlays the count and the count is not visible.
How can I put the count into the caption itself?
Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that this could not be done using the jssor code when the page is being created in php, so I instead calculated the total number of pictures from the php xpath query and inserted the "x of y" numbers and text into the caption in the php code.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you placed the `displayIndex` element inside a caption. You know, a caption should be a child element of a slide. It always moves along with the slide.

The more reasonable way is to make the `displayIndex` to be a static/fixed element.

A static/fixed element is an element parallel with every slide. It should be treated as a slide, but with `u="any"` attribute specified, it's no longer a slide, it will always stay where it should be.

```
<div u="slides">
    <div><!-- slide 1 --></div>
    <div><!-- slide 2 --></div>
    <div id='displayIndex' u='any' style='position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 790px; width: 100px; height: 26px;'>
        <!-- this is a static element -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-fixed-static-element.html

Comment: I found that the way I had the code set up, the first slide would have "1 of 27" in the caption, as I intended.  The issue was that it was only on the first slide.  None of the other slides had the count at all.  I figured it's because the slide show was being created in the php code on the server, and the javascript could not update the caption with the count afterwards.  It made sense to pull the numbers from the php code and put the count in the caption as the rest of the caption was created in the php code.  Thanks for the input.